# How do I share Facebook contents on Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm trying to share a post on my FB wall by an Android native app.

I'm following the official guide available @ [FBOfficial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android/)

I would know if it's possible to share a text, an image and an hashtag and also tag place or friends in the same post.

I tried to use the ShareContent class with no results.

If I use

```
new SharePhotoContent.Builder()...
```

it's not possible to add text, because the method "setQuote" is not available.

Otherwise, if I use

```
new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
```

it's not possible to add a picture.

I would also know why

```
setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder())
```

works perfectly but

```
setPlaceId(String placeId)
```

never works, also if I add a valid placeId taken from [PlaceIds](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id?hl=it)

Is there a way to solve my problem?

TY in advance

Comment: You can not share an image with a pre-defined text. Quote is only available for sharing links, but you can not specify the image yourself from within your app at this point, the image will be taken from the Open Graph meta data the shared link provides.

Comment: Ok, I understand your answer, but what about placeId?

Comment: _Google_ Place IDs have nothing to do with _Facebook_. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/

Comment: You're absolutely right.

I can close the question